# Is the "(daemon)" in Java Thread-Dumps reliable?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

We use multiple Thread-Pools in our Java Server,
and one of the Thread-Pool should only contain "deamon" Threads.

I use a Thread Factory, which calls setDaemon(true) for that pool,
and I use my own Thread sub-class, which looks like this:

```
private static final class DaemonThread extends Thread {
    public DaemonThread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target,
        String name, long stackSize) {
        super(group, target, name, stackSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!isDaemon()) {
            LOG.error("Wrong state for isDaemon(): false");
        }
        super.run();
    }
}
```

So, I'm expecting only to see something like this,
when I do a Thread-Dump:

```
"DAEMON-pool-1-thread-1234" Id=61 in WAITING on lock
    =java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2030c72c (daemon)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.company.thread.task.Task$TaskThreadFactory$DaemonThread.run(Task.java:194)

    Locked synchronizers: count = 0
```

But I also see something like this too (no "(daemon)"):

```
"DAEMON-pool-1-thread-3287" Id=3383 in TIMED_WAITING on lock
    =java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@69e4d79b
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.poll(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.poll(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.company.thread.task.Task$TaskThreadFactory$DaemonThread.run(Task.java:194)

    Locked synchronizers: count = 0
```

As you might have noticed from the bottom line,
the Thread that does *not* say "(daemon)" is of my sub-class.

Firstly, it should be daemon, because the thread-pool sets it,
and secondly, if it is not daemon, then I should see an error log,
which I cannot find in our logs either.

So, idk if the thread-dump output is "wrong", and the thread *is* daemon,
or if it is not daemon, and the log output is somehow lost,
or if somehow the daemon state is changed *after* the thread is created,
which is, AFAIK, not allowed:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-

> This method must be invoked before the thread is started.

Why do I want to know this? Because our Java server often doesn't shut down when it should, and I suspect it might be related to some threads not being daemon threads, when they should.